# Is it possible to have both links and subviews in a list in dashcode? My attempts have failed

Tags: javascript, web-applications, browser, hyperlink, dashcode

So I want to have a web app list that has some items go to external links when clicked and some items go to subviews when clicked.  What is the best way to achieve this?  I know I am close with this code, but I get a server error when I click the one that goes into a subview.

I have a javascript file that uses the keys "view" to go to a subview and "link" to go to a URL.  The view part works when I exclude the two lines concerning the link and vice-versa.

```
function itemClicked(event)
{
    var list = document.getElementById("manual").object;
    var browser = document.getElementById('browser').object;
    var selectedObjects = list.selectedObjects();

    if (selectedObjects && (1 == selectedObjects.length)){
         //The Browser's goForward method is used to make the browser push down to a     new level.
         //Going back to previous levels is handled automatically.
        view = selectedObjects[0].valueForKey("view")

    browser.goForward(document.getElementById(view),
    selectedObjects[0].valueForKey("name"));
    link = selectedObjects[0].valueForKey("link")

    var websiteURL2 = link;
    location = websiteURL2
}
```

}